# Traverse the DOM, put all anchor tags of a <ul> with an ID into an array,

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying get all the anchor tags from a list and put into an array by traversing the DOM, 
i've been able to get the list items and their .innerHTML into an array but taking it one step further and 
get each LI's anchor tag is not working. I've commented which lines don't work

```
<ul id="menu-list">
<li><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">List Item 4</a></li>                        
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
var list = document.getElementById('menu-list');
var listItems = list.getElementsByTagName('li'); //works
var listItemAnchors = listItems.firstChild //not working OR....
var listItemAnchors = listItems.childNode[0] //not working

var menuListItems = [];
for (i = 0; i < listItemAnchors.length; i++) {
    var arrValue = listItemsAnchors[i]
    menuListItems.push(arrValue);
    alert('item added');
}
</script>
```

Comment: If cross-browser support is not an issue for you. `var arrayOfAnchors = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#menu-list li a"));`

Comment: `listItems` is a **`NodeList`**, not a single DOM element. If you want to get the first child of each element, you have to iterate over the list.

Answer (score 2):

Why not to keep working with `getElementsByTagName` :

```
var listItemAnchors = list.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/cWNz8/

Comment: Because he wants only those which are in `<li>` tag

Comment: @Maxime: `li` elements are the only children of an `ul` element, so that should not be a problem.

Comment: @FelixKling Here, he select every `<a>` tag, even if they aren't in a list... I don't think it's what @TomCarden wants.

Comment: @Maxime: Uh? `list` refers to the `ul` element, so `list.getElementsByTagName('a')` refers to all `a` elements inside that `ul` element.

Comment: Ok, my bad, i read `document.getElements...`, it's the week-end, brain is off :-)

Comment: I think people are getting confused with `document.getElementsByTagName()`

Comment: @TomCarden , `list.getElementsByTagName` gives you exactly what you want

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here;

```
var listItemAnchors = listItems.firstChild //not working OR....
var listItemAnchors = listItems.childNode[0] //not working
```

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a collection, so `listItemAnchors` is a group of elements (array like structure, could be a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) or [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/NodeList)) and doesn't have `firstChild` (or any other `Element` properties). You must iterate through all your `listItems`, or do what @Cherniv suggested and get the anchors straight from `list`.

Try [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/eM6N2/) if you want only the first anchor from each `li`. Otherwise @Cherniv's answer is the best solution;

```js
var list = document.getElementById('menu-list');
var listItems = list.getElementsByTagName('li');
var listItemAnchors = [];

var potentialAnchor;
//for each list item
for (var index = 0; index < listItems.length; ++index) {
    potentialAnchor = listItems[index].children[0];

    //check if it's an anchor
    if (potentialAnchor.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a')
        listItemAnchors.push(potentialAnchor);
}

console.log(listItemAnchors);
```

Comment: *"`getElementsByTagName()` returns an array"*: Not quite. It returns a `NodeList` or `HTMLCollection`, which are *array-like* objects, but they are not arrays (e.g. they don't have any of the array methods).

Comment: I guess I could be more specific. My point was that he couldn't just work on it in an array-programming like fashion

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray=[];
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    myArray.push(elements[i].innerHTML)
}
```